# codeigniter active record db query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I need a query that looks like:

```
select * from table where id=5 and (eid = 1 or eid = 2 or eid = 10)
```

and I have tried

```
$this->db->select()->from(MEMB_EVENTS);
$this->db->where('mID', $mID);
```

with various means of `where` `or_where` `get_where` and no luck forming a query similar to the above need was hoping someone could shed some light for me on the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You can do that by using something like

```
$this->db->select()->from(MEMB_EVENTS);
$this->db->where('mID', $mID);
$this->db->where("(eid='1' OR eid='2' OR eid='10')", NULL, FALSE);
```